# how to do xml parsing if chinese characters present

Tags: iphone

i have an xml with chinese charactes.

```
<A>增长的身体质量指数 (abc)  Name</A>
<B>年龄 adress</B>
```

i allocate parser with

```
xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url;
[xmlparser setDelegate:self];
[xmlparser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[xmlparser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[xmlparser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

[xmlparser parse];
```

here tags are in engilsh ,but some data in it is chinese.
with above xmlparser ,out of english characters are not able to parse and apps get crash.
is their any way chinese charactes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced that problem, then, I have changed the language to English.Now, that was f9.hope changing language to English will solve ur problem.

Comment: but in my case its not possible.beccoz apps launch in china